# How to run WLST in windows?

Tags: windows, weblogic, wlst

I tried to run WLST (on Windows XP) but i always get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/wlst
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.wlst
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: weblogic.wlst.  Program will exit.
```

I tried to run *user_projects/domains/my_domain/bin/setDomainEnv.cmd* and *wlserver_10.3/server/bin/setWLSEnv.cmd* but without any success, i always get this NoClassDefFoundError when i run **java weblogic.wlst myscript.py**. What should i do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To invoke WLST:

```
<WL_HOME>/common/bin/wlst.cmd myscript.py
```

Example:

```
C:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/bin/wlst.cmd myscript.py
```

The reason for your error is, `weblogic.jar` is not present in your `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Yeah, that was pretty easy! But why is it everywhere written that i should call  */user_projects/domains/my_domain/bin/setDomainEnv.cmd* or *wlserver_10.3/server/bin/setWLSEnv.cmd* and then i can run "java welogic.wlst myscript.py"?

Comment: Along with setWLSEnv there could be other files also that need to be invoked. Basically wlst.cmd/sh will take care of setting all the environment settings required for WLST.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do that every time you run the batch file.

1. From "My Computer" or "Computer" (depending on your version of Windows)
2. Click "Properties" or "System Properties"
3. Click "Advanced System Settings"
4. Add these **user** Environment Variables

   ```
   WL_HOME=C:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3
   ```

   and

   ```
   CLASSPATH=.;%WL_HOME%/server/lib/weblogic.jar
   ```

Comment: I found the python script demanded the server be located C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver.  I renamed the directory, added the environment variables above and everything worked.